# Question regarding composition of continuous functions and analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I have the following theorem: Suppose $F$ is continuous on an open domain $D$ and is holomorphic everywhere on D except a possibly on line L. Prove the $F$ is holomorphic everywhere on $D$

In the proof the author stated that it sufficed to consider the line L as the real line else we can consider $g(z)=f(Az+B)$ where $Az+B$ maps the real axis onto the line L. He then proceeded to say that the analyticity of $F$ on $D$ is the equivalent to the analyticity of $g$ on the corresponding region.

Can someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: This follows from the Schwartz reflection principle and the symmetry principle, since F extends continuously onto the line L.

Comment: im supposed to prove Schwartz reflection principle using this theorem

Comment: So, what is the question? Are you confused by the change of coordinates, or do you want a proof of the theorem?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro change in coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h(z) = Az +B$ is an entire function. I.e., it is analytic everywhere. The chain rule shows that the composition of analytic functions is analytic. Also, the composition of continuous maps is continuous.

So yes, $g = f\circ h$ is analytic on $h^{-1}(D\setminus L)$ and continuous on all of $h^{-1}(D)$.

Comment: Ok. But how does the analyticity of g on the real line now show that f is analytic on L

Comment: By the rest of the proof. This step merely moves to problem to the real line instead of an arbitrary line. The proof didn't end there.

Comment: As once the rest of the proof shows that g is analytic on the real line how does that translate to f being analytic on L. I know that if f is analytic then g would be too. But suppose we know that g is analytic does that imply that f is too?

Comment: $h$ is invertible , and its inverse is also an affine function.

Comment: Ah I see thanks