# Generalization of a theorem that asserts if a function is analytic in a region except at the points of a line, then it is analytic on the whole region

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Edit: The original question was about rectifiable curve $\gamma$, I realized that I am not mature enough in mathematics to do this case. Instead, I have proved (I hope) for the case where $\gamma$ is some analytic arc given by a $1-1$ parametrization. Is my proof correct, or could I improve it?

I have the following theorem from Newman's Complex Analysis:

Newman, Bak 7.7: Suppose $f$ is continuous on an open domain $D$ and is analytic everywhere on $D$ except a possibly on line $L$. Then, $f$ is analytic throughout $D$.

In this theorem, I read that if we replace the line segment $L$ with any analytic arc, we are okay. Here is my work:

We will prove first a short lemma:

Suppose $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ is a $1-1$ analytic function which $\gamma'$ never vanishes throughout the domain. Then there exists an open set $S$ containing $[a,b]$, where $\gamma$ preserves the conditions above.

Proof: By the definition of analyticity, we can extend the domain of $\gamma$ to some open set $S$. Moreover, if the points of $S$ are sufficiently close to $[a,b]$ and $\gamma$ fails to be $1-1$ throughout $S$, this would mean that $\gamma$ fails to be $1-1$ on $[a,b]$ as analyticity implies continuity throughout the domain $S$. Similarly, since $\gamma$ is analytic there and analytic functions are infinitely differentiable in their domains, $\gamma'$ is continuous throughout $S$, thus $\gamma' = 0$ would mean that $\gamma' = 0$ at some point $[a,b]$ which follows again from continuity. Thus, if we extend its domain to a sufficiently small open set, the $\gamma$ function preserves the conditions of the previous domain.

Theorem: Suppose $f$ is continuous throughout $D$, analytic throughout $D$ maybe except in a points of a curve which is given by the image of some $1-1$ analytic arc $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$, $\gamma'\neq 0$. Then $f$ is analytic throughout $D$.

Proof: $\gamma$ remains $1-1$ and analytic with $\gamma' \neq 0$ throughout some open set $S$ containing $[a,b]$ by the lemma above. Thus $\gamma^{-1}:\gamma(S)\to S$ exists and well-defined. Now consider the function $g(z) = f(\gamma(z))$. Note that $g([a,b])$ are just the possible exceptional points of $f$. Since $\gamma^{-1}$ exists throughout $\gamma(S)$, the function $g\circ \gamma^{-1} = f$. Note that $g$ is analytic throughout $S$ which contains a possible exception of a line segment $[a,b]$ on the real axis, thus *Newman, Bak 7.7* guarantees that $g$ is analytic throughout $S$, since composition of analytic functions are analytic $f$ is analytic throughout $\gamma(S)$, hence is analytic throughout the arc $\gamma([a,b]]$. Since the arc contains only possible exceptional points, $f$ is analytic throughout $D$.

[Question regarding composition of continuous functions and analytic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3487944/question-regarding-composition-of-continuous-functions-and-analytic-function)

Comment: A rectifiable curve is not necessarily analytic.

Comment: Then it seems it is much more impossible to extend this proof via this method. Is there any other way to do this? (I mean within the realm of elementary theory of complex analysis)

Answer (score 1):

It is true that if a function $f$ is continuous on a domain $D$ and analytic on $D \setminus \Gamma$, where $\Gamma \subset D$ is a rectifiable curve, then $f$ is analytic on the whole domain $D$.

For a proof, see Section 3.2 of the survey article:

[https://math.hawaii.edu/~myounsi/Removable.pdf](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Emyounsi/Removable.pdf)

Comment: Unfortunately, my background is not sufficient to read this proof thoroughly. I edited the question and restricted it to analytic arcs instead of rectifiable curves. Would you have a suggestion to handle this? Thanks a lot.